# In Ruby, how do I add multiple user input in f.number_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, web-applications

I'm a complete Ruby noob so please explain things to me like I'm 5. I have a form that has seven f.number_fields. I would like to add them and store them in :total. Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
      <%= f.label :icecream %><br>
      <%= f.number_field :icecream %>

      <%= f.label :cake %><br>
      <%= f.number_field :cake %>
```

So in this case I would like to take the user input from :icecream and :cake and add them and store it in :total, but how would I do that? This would then be stored in the database.

Comment: Are you want to see result in same page or it will be stored to database after submit? .. can you please add full form ?

Comment: yes, after clicking submit it would be stored to total in the databse

Comment: can you please add model and controller methods related to that..

Comment: It really seems as if you are trying to run before you can even crawl here. You're probably at the beginning of a Rails tutorial or course, but you're letting your imagination get ahead of your (current level of) ability. I can see this one question spawning pages and pages of remedial level instruction, and that's not really what Stack Overflow is about. First, figure out what models, views and controllers are and how they work together, otherwise nothing anyone else says will make any sense.

Comment: Did this every end up working out for you?

Answer (score 0):

Ok you have your form in your view your model and your controller. What is going to happen is you are going to fill out your form that is in the new view for totals. Hit the submit button, that is going to make a request to your controller action `create`. In the `create` action it is going to make a call to the `total_params` method which is just going to check the `params` hash (which contains all the information that was just in you form in the view) to make sure it has values for the `:total` key and it will allow `:cake` and `:icecream` to be passed in (this is call strong parameters or white listing parameters), the `private` keyword is just so the `total_params` action is not directly accessed from outside the controller. Then in the `create` method the `each` look is going to iterate over the values in the hash returned by the call to `total_params` then add it to the variable total_value. One the each loop has finished a `Total` record will be created in they database with a `total` column value that is the sum of `icecream` and `cake`. This is approximately how you would go about storing a value.

View

```
  #app/views/totals/new.html.erb
  <%= form_for @total, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :icecream %><br>
  <%= f.number_field :icecream %>

  <%= f.label :cake %><br>
  <%= f.number_field :cake %>
  <%= f.submit %>
```

Controller

```
  #app/controllers/totals_controller.rb

  class TotalsController << ApplicationController

    def create
      total_value = 0

      total_params.each do |k, v|
      total_value += v
      end
      Total.create(total: total_value)
    end

    private

    def total_params
      params.require(:total).permit(:cake, :icecream)
    end
  end
```

Model

```
 #app/models/total.rb

 class Total << ActiveRecord::Base
 end
```